# not able to add core data file to my existing project(version control issue)...?

Tags: ios, core-data, version-control

I have application with iOS Deployment Target 4.0, now I want to add Data Model file lying under iOS-Core Data.But when I try to add this file into my project below message alerted to me...!?!

"The operation could not be performed because the file is not under version control."

I try this with test project, in which I create one small project and after that I add this file, but that have no issue
plz help

Comment: Having a similar problem, any ideas?

Comment: The file is located in a directory already under version control? Put a text file in the same location, try to add that to your project -does that work?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Xcode cannot find the file that your project is pointing to.  Try right-clicking on the file in Xcode and selecting **Show in Finder** to see if the file is there.  If not, you will need to copy the file into your project directory, and then add it to Xcode again.
2. Your git repo doesn't know about the file.

If it's the git issue, open Terminal and

```
cd directoryName/OfYour/File
git add .
git commit -am "Added file."
```

Comment: Cheers. I'd managed to sort it and although I'm using svn, what you suggest is essentially what I had to do to fix it.

Comment: Great to hear.  Can you post the svn workflow you used to resolve the issue for others who might encounter it?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a project template with core data so you have anything in place.
Instead of adding a new file (core data model) you could try to add the existing model file from new project.

From time to time (I use svn) it gets horribly confused when adding/deleting/replacing files under version control. In those case, even that one loose the version info, I start from the beginning.
I wrote a small tool(Automator) which deletes every .svn directory/subdirectory so you start whithout any version control.
I you need the tool I could provide a link to it.

Comment: Thanks for rely, I think, I got it what you are trying to say...!?!